# Grub loader not appearing on boot when dual booting with Windows 7

Tags: grub2, windows

I've just dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but whenever I boot my computer the grub loader asking me which OS I want to boot into doesn't appear and I get launched straight into Windows. I installed Windows First, and they're on the same HDD, on consecutive partitions.

Any help appreciated,
Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)

Answer (score 6):

### Try to show the Grub menu

Hold down the
   <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as the computer attempts to boot to display the GRUB 2
   menu. In certain circumstances, if holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key method does
   not display the menu pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key repeatedly may display the
   menu.

If that doesn't work, then Grub somehow got removed or corrupted. Use Boot Repair to reinstall and fix it.

### Boot Repair

#### Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

#### Repair the bootloader

To restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

#### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running by now.