# Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.10, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10 with UEFI. To install Ubuntu, I chose the option **install alongside Windows 10** or something similar to this. Then I created a new partition for Ubuntu and installed it. After installation, the boot menu did not show up. Initially I thought Ubuntu has not been installed, but when I plugged in the USB drive and wanted to install Ubuntu I saw an option of reinstalling Ubuntu on my machine. So, I found out that Ubuntu is installed. Pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> also does not help.

Can anyone help me bring up the GRUB boot menu?

In Windows, I also entered the command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in cmd, but still the boot menu does not show up.

***Reply*** (Himanshu) :
Just boot in bios and, if you can, *`add boot option`* with name say *`ubuntu`* and path *`EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`*. No need for live PCB or anything. Move the boot option to top. This is for dell GUI bios but I assume it works for all. Or you may want to see [this](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/enable-or-disable-windows-boot-manager-screen.html#:%7E:text=Just%20click%20the%20Cortana%20Search,pops%20up%2C%20and%20press%20Enter.) or [this](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-windows-10-linux/), where you can enable *`Windows Boot Loader`* for one boot or forever as you wish, and boot Ubuntu from it. If you want now, you can use the installed *`Ubuntu terminal`* to use the commands *`update-grub`* to use GRUB instead. *(Not enough reputation to answer properly btw.)*

Comment: You can try using the `boot-repair` tool

Comment: its not working for me.

Comment: I tried several of the answers below, none worked. This solution worked for me: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=368217

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. On Windows 10, go to the *start menu*.
2. Search and open *Recovery Options*. The description for it should say *System settings*.
3. Under *Advanced startup* click *Restart now*.
4. Click *Use a device*; it's description should say
   "Use a USB drive, network connection, or Windows recovery DVD".
5. Click *Ubuntu* and hopefully it should take you to the grub boot menu.
6. Next try going back to the live Ubuntu session on the USB to reinstall `grub-efi`. On the live session, open a terminal and enter the following commands in:

   > ```
   > sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt
   > ```
   >
   > Replace the hashtag in `/dev/sda#` with the number representing the  partition where you had Ubuntu installed. You can check using `gnome-disks` or `gparted`.
   >
   > ```
   > sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt/boot/efi
   > ```
   >
   > Replace the hashtag in `/dev/sda#` with the number representing the EFI partition. It's usually `/dev/sda2`.
   >
   > ```
   > sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   > sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
   > sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
   > sudo mount -o bind /run /mnt/run
   > sudo chroot /mnt/
   > sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
   > sudo update-grub
   > ```
   >
   > Reboot.
7. If that fails, go to your BIOS settings with one of the F keys; that option might be *Enter setup*. Look for boot option priorities and move *Ubuntu* above the *Windows Boot Manager*. Go to the option to save the changes then reboot.
8. Lastly you can try using [Boot-Repair](https://askubuntu.com/a/694130/51672).

Comment: Thank you.  I followed the steps you mentioned.  Everything worked except the last steps. I even followed the boot-repair tool tutorial. It still does not work. However, there has been a change! Now when I click on `Recovery Options` and eventually select `Ubuntu`, GRUB gets loaded and I see more options there. One of the options is Windows now! But when the computer gets restarted I again need to login into Windows and do the same thing to load up GRUB. What should I do?

Comment: @Amir, try going to the BIOS and make sure `ubuntu` is 1st on the boot priority list. If you can log-in to ubuntu, try running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I followed steps 1 to 4. Now, in step 5, I do not have an "Ubuntu" option. I have only two options: USB NIC (IPV4) and USB NIC (IPV6). What should I do from here?

Comment: Also, when I try "sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt/boot/efi", I get an error: "/mnt/boot/efi: mount point does not exist". Indeed, there is no folder "efi" in /mnt/boot - there is a folder "grub".

Comment: Also, when I try "sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi" I get an error: "E: Package grub-efi has no installation candidate" (I have Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi `grub-efi` is in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and also Ubuntu 18.10. You can check it by running `apt policy grub-efi`. I ran a simulated install of `grub-efi` in 18.04 and it didn't return any errors.

Comment: @karel maybe it's because I run from a live USB?

Comment: `grub-efi` is from the main repository, so it would ordinarily be installable from a live USB session.

Comment: Strangely, I can install grub-efi when I do this command *before* the "sudo chroot /mnt/", when my prompt is "$" (it is then updated to version 2.02-2ubnutu8.2). However, when I do the same command *after* the "sudo chroot /mnt/" (when my prompt is "#"), I get an error saying "no installation candidate".

Moreover, when I do "sudo update-grub", I get an error: "failed to get canonical path of /cow".

Comment: In any case, after installing grub-efi (before the chroot) and running update-grub (after th chroot), I reboot, go to BIOS setup, and still do not see any Ubuntu option - the only option I see is "Windows Boot Manager".

Answer (score 8):

I have read many answers and tried accordingly but the problem was still there, so I decided to do it myself as follows:

1. Click the Start menu and select *Settings*.
2. Select UPDATE & SECURITY.
3. Click *Recovery*.
4. Under *Advanced startup*, click the *Restart now* button. The system will restart and show the Windows 10 boot menu.

   [image]
5. Select *Troubleshoot*.
6. Choose *Advanced options*.

   [image]
7. Select *UEFI Firmware Settings*.
8. Click *Restart* to restart the system and enter UEFI (BIOS) setup utility.
9. F10 BIOS setup -> *System Configuration* tab ->
   *Boot Options* -> *OS Boot Manager* ->
   Ubuntu -> (select the Ubuntu option and move this option up to the top of the list) ->
   F10 *Save and Exit* (press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save Ubuntu as the default boot option) ->
   F10 (press <kbd>F10</kbd> again to save the changes to the BIOS/UEFI setup utility)

   [image]

When the computer restarts, the Ubuntu boot menu will be shown.

Comment: This solved my issue. It turns out that in the BIOS the "OS Boot Manger" option in the UEFI Boot Order opens up another menu to select either Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been trying to do this for so long and this was the solution.  Also to elaborate. You don't need to do all that. If you know your bios key at boot you can just press that and do it at boot).  Also it says ubuntu but that's actually the menu you want

Answer (score 4):

Live boot Ubuntu and select try Ubuntu option from the GRUB menu that appears and then install boot repair by typing in following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm presuming GRUB successfully installed, but something is clearly amiss. I know you said you already tried bcdedit, but here's the command to set it: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. If you set this and could not boot, as you have indicated already, don't forget to rescind the change you made using `bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.

Try following the steps detailed in [Enkouyami's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/717954/85695) (i.e. chrooting into your installed Ubuntu system from the live CD and then reinstalling grub manually).

If the above fail, you could try installing [grub2win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/files/). This allows you to boot grub2 from your Windows EFI firmware by making edits to the boot code. **Be sure to follow the instructions carefully** on the project's page if taking choosing method.

Another method instead of grub2win is [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/), which is a live CD that allows you to boot into a variety of operating systems. I would try this first instead of grub2win, as there is less risk involved if something goes awry. I have not used Super Grub2 Disk personally, but I hear it is an incredibly useful tool. Using this tool, you can restore grub by following the instructions [here](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in `/etc/default/grub` called `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` which prevents the GRUB menu from showing during the timeout period unless you press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Check to see if this setting is enabled by `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`, and if it is enabled open the `/etc/default/grub` file for editing in nano text editor and disable it.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Comment out the line that says `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` by preceding it with a `#` character. Make sure that the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value there is set to a value larger than zero, for example `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`. Save the file.

Then run the `update-grub` command and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub  
sudo reboot
```

<sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Other useful links

- [How to repair GRUB2 when Ubuntu won't boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884()/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)
- [Using EasyBCD to boot to GRUB from Windows boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu/140376#140376)
- [Installing GRUB2 Ubuntu documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for live PCB or anything.

> Just boot in BIOS (press F2 in Dell Inspiron) and, *Add boot option* with name say *ubuntu* and path `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`.
> Move the boot option to top. (This is for Dell GUI BIOS, but I assume it works for all.)

Assuming everything else was installed normally, this would work very fine.

> Once booted, you can use the installed *Ubuntu terminal* to use the commands `update-grub` to use GRUB instead, if that's what you want.

Here are some links you should go through to get ideas about other things possible with boots (and self-help).

1. [Enable or disable Windows Boot Manager](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/enable-or-disable-windows-boot-manager-screen.html#:%7E:text=Just%20click%20the%20Cortana%20Search,pops%20up%2C%20and%20press%20Enter.)
2. [Dual-boot Windows 10 and Linux](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-windows-10-linux/)

You can enable Windows Boot Loader for one boot or always as you wish, and boot Ubuntu from it.

Comment: Thanks Karel. I like the formatting and would definitely try to follow.