# Grub does not launch on dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop since some days. However after it's installed GRUB is never launcher and Windows starts directly with no chance to launch Ubuntu.

I've tried with Windows 7 and the same happened, and now with Windows 10 it's still the same. However I installed it a friend's laptop and there's no problem.

Help me please. I've tried many methods I found on the Internet and still nothing.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The computer could be booting directly to the Windows partition. Try changing the boot order in your BIOS options.

Comment: It could also be a secure boot or EFI issue, it depends how each OS was installed.
Check the EFI settings first. If that doesn't turn anything up, try to reinstall grub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable Secure boot in BIOS
2. Disable fastboot and hibernation in Windows
3. Try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if that is still not working

> ```
>  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>  sudo apt-get update
>  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

When i used to do boot-repair at the end of pastebin contents it has these lines

```
> If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot
> order in your BIOS. If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot
> order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader. For
> example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in
> an admin command prompt: **bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path
> \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi**
```

Try this command
**bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path  \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi**
The above command works in Windows 8 as well as 10 but this should be the last resort unless your boot-repair options gives you this option only

Comment: It's hard to add repositories and install software when you can't get into Ubuntu in the first place ;-). Maybe suggest the bootable option instead.