# Removing Ubuntu Grub from motherboard firmware

Tags: grub2, windows, uninstall, cuda

I created a dual boot of linux with Windows 10. I installed NVIDIA drivers then installed cuda toolkit. It asked if I wanted to update the Grub, I said yes. After that I was no longer able to access Ubuntu. I select Ubuntu in the boot menu and it just goes to Windows. I have tried many things and it seems to me the Grub is on the motherboard firmware.

I tried to start over by reformatting everything. I have deleted my hard drives and reinstalled Windows 10 however the Ubuntu boot option is still listed there. The problem is if I install Ubuntu it still goes straight to windows even after selecting ubuntu in the boot menu. I would like to get rid of this option then install Ubuntu again from scratch.

I have already tried the following:

This tries to reinstall the grub [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)

I have tried boot repair from ubuntu and windows

Ubuntu: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

For windows: if I run bootrec /fixboot I get access denied if I run bootrec /fixMbr it completes succesfully but does not fix anything

My last resort was try to get the computer back to factory settings but even after deleting both hard drives and installing a fresh copy of Windows the Ubuntu boot option is still there and causes a conflict when I actually install Ubuntu and thus it goes straight to Windows.

Comment: delete the /efi/boot/ubuntu folder in the EFI partition

Comment: I have deleted this. The ubuntu boot option is still there.

Comment: You're probably in UEFI mode, so messing around with legacy MBR boot will do nothing for you. Go into UEFI settings/BIOS and delete ubuntu from the boot order. Or if efibootmgr is available on an install-media, run it and delete the ubuntu entry.

Comment: More details: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am guessing, you want to erase GRUB and like me, have failed to do so after `bootrec` stuff doesn't work. This is what worked for me. I downloaded the official Arch Linux ISO, Live booted it into a USB. After that, at the startup, there is an option of dropping into a shell. Select that. Then, `shell>` prompt will show up.

enter `fs0:` (or) whatever your drives get named at the startup. They will show up in the 
prompt when you press enter on the option.

type ls

You get the files with Bootloader entries.
Search for the file name 'Ubuntu'
erase it (be careful) not to erase any other file.
reboot your PC.

You will see that the extra bootloader entry has disappeared. :)

Do not hesitate to share this knowledge.

Oh!, and one more thing:

If bootrec says `Access denied`, do this:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootsect/nt60 sys           //mind well there is NO SPACE before or after the '/'
bootrec /fixmbr             //it now works!!
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Errr..... Can any nice guy out there explain to me why bootsect/nt60 sys needs to be fired?? (and that too not always?)

Comment: But this worked for me; maybe because I booted in UEFI mode (arch supports that)

Comment: Oops, posted to ans instead of quest.  If your fix worked, you're in legacy mode.

Comment: Anyways, will you please help me with the bootsect thing?

Comment: You should ask your own question, this question is a totally different situation from yours.  Well, really, restoring the Windows Boot Rec/sector has already been answered, so do a few searches of this site.