# Ubuntu installed but unbootable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am currently having trouble booting to the Ubuntu image I just installed.

### How I installed it:

#### BIOS Settings:

- Legacy/UEFI => UEFI
- Secure Boot => Enabled / Custom
- Boot => USB

#### Steps Taken:

1. Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Put it onto a bootable USB drive using UUI ***(But it would not show up when booting in UEFI so I used Rufus)***
3. Shrunk Windows 10 Partition
4. Booted into BIOS, changed the settings.
5. Closed BIOS
6. Booted into Ubuntu USB
7. Clicked Next, Next, Next...
8. Chose "Install alongside Windows Boot Manager"
9. *I believe it was looking at a different hard drive so I clicked "Another Option" cleared that one and set up a Ext4/swap partitions on the same SSD as Windows 10 in the "free space"*
10. I go through the motions and install and it says everything went swell and that I just need to reboot.

### After I Installed it:

When booting it takes me straight to Windows 10 every time (No GRUB or anything). so I looked around and found [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win). I followed it until step 5 where I was in GRUB. I see "Ubuntu and Windows 10" so I click Ubuntu and it freezes with immediately after on a blank screen (Ubuntu themed gradient background) and it just stays there.

Comment: What brand/model computer? What video card/chip? If you have nVidia, you may need nomodeset until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Mobo: MSI - B350 TOMAHAWK ATX AM4 Motherboard
GC: Zotac - GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 6GB AMP! Edition Video Card
CPU: AMD - Ryzen 5 1600 3.2GHz 6-Core Processor

Comment: Also the PC I built myself. I'll try that when I get back to my computer, seems like that could be it. But would it also explain GRUB not booting normally?

Comment: I hope you still see these. I got it to work so I can boot into Ubuntu but even when I hold down `Right Shift` on boot it goes straight to Windows. I can still get to it through `Advanced Startup>Restart Now>USB/HDD>Ubuntu` but then on restart it goes back to windows

Comment: Have you read through this very long, but very helpful answer?   The good news is that both your installs are bootable!  You just need to force them to give you the choice. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi  Skip down to the part labled Your Computer Boots Directly to Windows

Comment: I tried various things but ultimately the things I think that helped were fixing the graphics card and using boot-repair. Which told me if it didn't work immediately to use `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` and now it boots to GRUB ... Going to get grub customizer so I can put windows at the top and put Ubuntu 2nd. Thank you both for all the help ! I'm not sure what to do as this feels like a wasted question because the answers are elsewhere I just needed one answer before using the next. Let me know please !