# GRUB is not displaying on boot, no GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have GRUB v 2.8.9 (Ubuntu 18.10). I want to install Remix OS in dual boot. I created an entry for Remix OS with GRUB Customizer. But when I'm trying to boot, I don't have any GRUB menu appearing.

So, I tried to fix that by editing `/etc/default/grub`, but there's no line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`. I do have `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"`.

How can I show my GRUB on boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: @MohammadC i do not have line: "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT", to do this

Comment: Just add it to the file and dont forget to update grub

Comment: @MohammadC i must comment line "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT" to solve this problem, but if i add this line in code, and comment it, then, either first variant nor second will not work, because both in 2 variants this line of code will not be compiling

Comment: I just wanna to make the grub to open permanently, when i am booting my pc.

Comment: Okay. I shall check my grub and post it. My grub works. Comes up everytime has a timeout of a few seconds. My grub has a theme so some of it will be irrelevant. Mine also selects the last OS used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/)

Comment: Not really a dupe of anything, definitely not the second one - no Windows installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are my GRUB settings, which do what you want. Make a backup of your `/etc/default/grub` file and try mine to see if does what you want.

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` any time you edit the file...

I noticed my `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line doesn't have quotes and

- 0 means do not time out so skips menu,
- postive number means skip menu after the given number of secs and
- -1 means don't skip.

Also try removing the quotes from `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`. Also try setting that to `menu`, not `countdown` or `hidden`.

Check out [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) to see what each setting does.

I think these are the main settings you need.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
```

**My current `/etc/default/grub`**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/Aurora-Penguinis-GRUB2/theme.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try it tomorrow, i think it should work.