# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on ssd sata and ssd M.2

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 10 installed on SSD (240GB plugged in sata express slot) and then I have plugged M.2 SSD (240GB) to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it. In the end of installing Ubuntu 18.04 the setup program gives message about failing to install bootloader.
GParted shows initial partitions including Windows on /dev/sdb and Ubuntu related partition - on /dev/sda.
I have googled and looked through some articles about dual booting but I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Ubuntu installer failed to install the grub bootloader because there isn't a 500 MB FAT32-formatted EFI System partition on `/dev/sda` (M.2 240GB SSD). If the Ubuntu installer did not create this EFI System partition the first time, then you can select *Try Ubuntu* and use the built-in GParted partition editor to create a 500MB EFI System partition formatted as FAT32 at the start of disk `/dev/sda` manually. Then run the Ubuntu installer again. If the Ubuntu installation is successful, the Ubuntu installer will run all the way through the installation this time including installing the grub bootloader.

Comment: I added 500MB Fat32 partition in the beginning on /dev/sda (M.2 240GB SSD) as you mention and selected drive for installing boot loader /dev/sda. In this case Ubuntu 18.04 setup completed successfully, but when I restarted computer Ubuntu boot loader haven't appeared at all and have been loaded Windows 10. In next installation I have selected drive for installing boot loader /dev/sdb, but in this case the setup programm have been failed and gave the same message about failing to install bootloader.

Comment: The first case  in which you selected the drive for installing boot loader as `/dev/sda` is the better choice because the Ubuntu installer installed grub on the same drive as Ubuntu was installed on + it can boot to Windows. I recommend booting from the same Ubuntu USB that you used to install and installing Boot-Repair on the Ubuntu USB from a live session ("Try Ubuntu") and run the Recommended repair. If that doesn't work try the answers to [Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/q/717904/).