# Lenovo firmware upgrade on Ubuntu, how to not lose grub multiboot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, upgrade, lenovo

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P15 Gen 1 with Windows 10 Pro 64 pre-installed. I installed some time ago Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS as a dual boot with grub on a secondary partition.

Now, I've some firmware upgrades left behind, at least 4 of them.

I want to upgrade them but I fear I'll lose the multi-boot and I'll not be able to login to Ubuntu anymore, and Ubuntu is my working environment, I use Windows for games only.

So, my questions are:

1. Should I run the firmware upgrades from my Ubuntu installation or from the Windows one (the main default)?
2. How can I recover my Ubuntu installation if, after the firmware upgrade, Windows will start automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this one help you after installing firmware update https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264060/grub-menu-not-showing-up-on-boot-after-firmware-update#answer-1332622

Comment: thanks @RobinHood, any suggestion to avoid that? :) also, is there any difference between upgrading from Windows or from Ubuntu?