# Dual-boot, Grub menu doesn't shows Ubuntu entry - Acer F5-573G

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10

I have an ACER Aspire F 15

I used to use my PC with 2 hard drive: a little SSD where is installed windows and a larger hard disk with data and 3 little partition for Ubuntu's /root, /home and swap-memory.
Some time ago, I changed the SSD with a larger one and reinstalled windows 10.
Now, when I start my PC pressing a F key and choose to boot ubuntu from the hard disk, it boot Win anyway.

If I re-insert the old SSD, I can normally boot ubuntu.

I also tried to make a backup of my old data in Ubuntu's partitions. Than tryed to reinstall ubuntu on a new partition in my new SSD, the larger one, but it doesn't even show a corrisponding new entry in the list of bootable OS. Can someone help me?

I tried several times also the solutions in these answered questions:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

[Dual-boot boot menu does not show up after installing Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717904/dual-boot-boot-menu-does-not-show-up-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-win)

and some others about how to repair grub.

Comment: You have an UEFI boot entry for Ubuntu that uses the GUID/partUUID of the ESP. If you created a new ESP, the UEFI entry is incorrect & you do not have Ubuntu/grub2's boot files in new ESP. Easiest to use Boot-Repair from your Ubuntu live installer and its advanced mode to totally reinstall grub (& kernel often just to update it).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode, since Windows should be UEFI.

Comment: I tryed but it doesn't worked. I removed now also removed the partitions of ubuntu in the data hard disk and tried to reinstall ubuntu, but nothing changed

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI boot mode? What brand/model system? Some like Acer require "trust" in UEFI settings. Some like HP require you to change boot order in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu).

Comment: I have an ACER Aspire F 15. I am already in UEFI boot mode, changed by the UEFI interface, furthermore I have also disabled secure boot

Comment: If you reinstalled, rerun Boot-Repair & post link to summary report. And check if you need "trust" setting in UEFI settings. May show details: Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 and Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: I tryed all you wrote, but I don't know how to check if I need trust settings. 
Here my summary report link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HrjGzVtG4h/

Comment: Your "unknown" entry needs you to trust it in Acer's UEFI settings. See Boot 0001 on line 35 of report. Some more user with trust setting info. Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969
Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947

Comment: Thanks so much! This link ( https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 ) worked! With my acer, I had to able secure boot, in order to select files as trusted. But it definitely worked!!
Now I had to remove the old entries in the window booting menu, but I'm already so happy with this!